# `pass` not asking for password anymore - gnome-keyring or gpg-agent related? How can I force password asking?

Tags: password-management, gnupg

I cross-posted this on the manjaro forums and on server fault. So far no answer, so trying here.

I have gnome-keyring running for sure, not sure it's gnome-keyring or gpg-agent or ssh-agent related...

I use `pass` as command line password manager for many things. Usually, when querying `pass`, a dialog would appear asking me to enter a password first. I assume it was `gnome-keyring` asking me for my password. It may well be `gpg-agent` or `ssh-agent` - I don't know.

However, since some time ago, it does not ask my password anymore - thus, anyone with access to my shell can use `pass` to see my passwords, as they are printed on STDOUT. I must have clicked on the option to somehow save my password I guess.

I want to enable `pass` to ask me for my password again. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if either or both the gpg-agent or gnome-keyring daemons are running. Some display managers will automatically start gnome-keyring. I've never used it. [gpg-agent](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GnuPG#gpg-agent) is a separate daemon and can sometimes cause conflict.

In `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`, you can declare to cache your gpg key password for a period of time. My config reads:

```
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry
default-cache-ttl 60480000
max-cache-ttl 60480000
```

Which will cache the password for the maximum amount of time. I use the /usr/bin/pinentry GUI application to pop-up and ask for the password the first time something like `pass` asks for it. This would not work on a headless system; I think by default it just asks on the command-line.